# why rec.area and rec.perimeter are always 0?

Tags: java, methods

I don't understand why the rec.area and rec.perimeter are printed 0 only

**Rectangles**

```
class Rectangles {

        int weight;
        int height;
        int area;
        int perimeter;

        int area (int weight, int height) {
            return  weight * height;
        }

        int perimeter (int weight, int height) {
            return  2 * (weight + height);
        }
    }
```

**RectanglesTest**

```
class RectanglesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        Rectangles rec = new Rectangles();

        rec.weight = 10; 
        rec.height = 15; 

        System.out.println(rec.weight);
        System.out.println(rec.height);
        System.out.println(rec.area);
        System.out.println(rec.perimeter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because nowhere you assign a value to either `area` or `perimeter`.

Comment: You shouldn't name methods the same as fields, it is missleading (as shown on your example). If you actually call the method you will get the results you expect. like `rec.area()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing field names with method names - best to make them different, but anyway with your code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Rectangles rec = new Rectangles();

  rec.weight = 10; 
  rec.height = 15; 

  System.out.println(rec.weight);
  System.out.println(rec.height);
  System.out.println(rec.area ());
  System.out.println(rec.perimeter ());
}
```

As you are using fields, then no other parameters are needed to be passed to these methods, so change them to

```
int area () { ....}
int perimeter () { ....}
```

*better to name methods are verbs e.g. calcArea*

In fact you do not use

```
int area;
int perimeter;
```

so you could delete them

Comment: Probably also need to point out that the `area()` and `perimeter()` methods need to be properly implemented too...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks, I did not see this.  WFH ?

Comment: Nah, got to fax a request each week

Answer (score 0):

because `area` and `perimeter` values didn't change, in your methods you have to make them `void` and assign the calculated values to the requested attributes

```
class Rectangles {

        int weight;
        int height;
        int area;
        int perimeter;

        void area () {
            area = weight * height;
        }

        void perimeter () {
            perimeter = 2 * (weight + height);
        }
}
```

and in your `main` method, you have to call the methods before

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Rectangles rec = new Rectangles();

  rec.weight = 10; 
  rec.height = 15; 
  rec.area();
  rec.perimeter();
  System.out.println(rec.weight);
  System.out.println(rec.height);
  System.out.println(rec.area);
  System.out.println(rec.perimeter);
}
```

Comment: Then you would have to additionally call the methods to assign those values.